# pandas category: keep only most common ones and replace rest with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

In a `pd.Series` with `dtype=category` I have 253 unique values. Some of these occur quite often and others occur only once or twice. Now I would like to keep only the top 10 of these and replace the rest with `np.nan`.

I got as far as `top = df['cats'].value_counts().head(10)` to create the categories I want to keep. But now?

Something along the lines of `df['cats'].apply(cat_replace, args=top)`?

```
def cat_replace(c, top):
    if c in top:
        return c
    else:
        return np.nan
```

This however doesn't look too 'pandas' to me and I have a feeling there is a better way. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'cats': pd.Categorical(
        list('abcdefghij') * 5
        + list('klmnopqrstuvwxyz'))}
)

top_n = 10
top_cats = df['cats'].value_counts().head(top_n).index.tolist()
df.loc[~df['cats'].isin(top_cats), 'cats'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Just trying to be helpful: `cats = ['Abyssinian', 'Bobtail', 'Curl', 'Shorthair', 'Wirehair', 'Balinese', 'Bengal', 'Bombay', 'Burmese', 'Rex', 'Burmilla', 'Mau', 'Havana', 'Javanese', 'Korat', 'LaPerm']; np.random.seed([3, 1415]); df = pd.DataFrame({'cats': np.random.choice(cats, 1000)})`

Answer (score 0):

Cribbing from

[How can I keep the rows of a pandas data frame that match a particular condition using value_counts() on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291703/how-can-i-keep-the-rows-of-a-pandas-data-frame-that-match-a-particular-condition)

You could look at doing something like

```
top = set(df['cats'].value_counts().head(10))
df['cats'].apply(top.__contains__)
```